# Save Data as Binary Using ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

My application lets users choose some objects, and when they hit "submit", it is sent to the model. When the user presses "save" then currently the model is outputted to a fileName.dat and this file can be loaded back into the application and this will load their selected object.

It works flawlessly, however, I want to be able to save the model in a binary format and then be able to load that file. I want to do this using ObjectOutputStream, or if this isn't possible then I don't mind using another method.

This is my code:

```
//------- save the data model -------
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("profileObj.dat"));) {

            oos.writeObject(model); //writes the model object to a file
            oos.flush();

            alertDialogBuilder("Information Dialog", "Save success", "Profile information saved to profileObj.dat");
        }
        catch (IOException ioExcep){
            System.out.println("Error saving");
            ioExcep.printStackTrace(); //this is for debugging
            }
```

Thank you :)

EDIT:
This is what the file is currently saved as (this is what shows up when I open the .dat file in SublimeText)

```
aced 0005 7372 0014 6d6f 6465 6c2e 5374
7564 656e 7450 726f 6669 6c65 73ee 74e0
2b5e 686b 0200 074c 0006 636f 7572 7365
7400 0e4c 6d6f 6465 6c2f 436f 7572 7365
3b4c 0004 6461 7465 7400 154c 6a61 7661
2f74 696d 652f 4c6f 6361 6c44 6174 653b
4c00 0565 6d61 696c 7400 124c 6a61 7661
2f6c 616e 672f 5374 7269 6e67 3b4c 0007
```

Comment: The way your code is written it should already accomplish what you ask for... whats the problem?

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman does it output in binary? When I open the .dat file in SublimText, it shows up as hexadecimal (I'll update the post so you can see)

Comment: Yup that is certainly binary. Since I sorta answered this question and it is now resolved i added it as an answer below. If you feel it answers your question please approve it as the correct answer (the grey check mark next to the answer)

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman I thought binary was 1's and 0's? Sorry, I am new to saving/loading in java and so I am a bit confused.

Comment: on your hard drive it is 1's and 0's. Your editor can display binary in many different forms so as to be easy to read. It can show it as text (in which case it would look garbled and random), it could show it in binary form, or hexdecimal form. The most common way to render binary data for a user to review would be as hexdecimal which is exactly what your editor is doing.

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman Ohh that makes a lot of sense! Thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current solution already works for what you want it to do. The output would be binary.

For the details of how to serialize to binary vs other formats (such as XML) the following is a [good tutorial](http://mrbool.com/differences-between-binary-serialization-and-serialization-in-java/31208). As you can see your method is described here as the correct way to serialize to binary.